# How to add themes?

Tags: python, tkinter, themes, ttk

I just picked up python recently and I've been working on a project called "ToDoList.py".It's finished but I want to add a button to change the theme of the GUI using `tkinter / ttk` but its not working.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "todolist.py", line 64, in <module>
    lbl_title = Label(root, text="ToDoList", bg="white")
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 761, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::label", kw)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 559, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2296, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"
```

I don't understand why this error is possible since i haven't adjusted the widgets yet

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter.ttk import *

from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk

import random

import tkinter.messagebox

#--------root style
root = Tk()
#--------root backgroud
root.configure(bg="white")
#--------root title
root.title("Reminder")
#--------root size
root.geometry("225x300")
#--------create empty list
tasks = []
#--------fuction
def darkmd():
    root.get_themes()
    root.set_theme("equilux")
#--------command
lbl_title = Label(root, text="ToDoList", bg="white")
lbl_title.grid(row=0, column=0)

lbl_display = Label(root, text="", fg="black", bg="white")
lbl_display.grid(row=0, column=1)

txt_input = Entry(root, width=20, fg="black", bg="white")
txt_input.grid(row=1, column=1)

bt_add_task = Button(root, text="Add Task", fg="black", bg="white",         command = add_task)
bt_add_task.grid(row=1, column=0)

bt_del_all = Button(root, text="Del all", fg="black", bg="white", command = del_all)
bt_del_all.grid(row=2, column=0)

bt_del_one= Button(root, text="Del", fg="black", bg="white", command = del_one)
bt_del_one.grid(row=3, column=0)

bt_sort_asc = Button(root, text="Sort (ASC)", fg="black", bg="white", command = sort_asc)
bt_sort_asc.grid(row=4, column=0)

bt_sort_desc = Button(root, text="Sort (DESC)", fg="black", bg="white", command = sort_desc)
bt_sort_desc.grid(row=5, column=0)

bt_total_task = Button(root, text="Num Of Task", fg="black", bg="white", command = total_task)
bt_total_task.grid(row=6, column=0)

bt_darkmd = Button(root, text="Darkmode", fg="black", bg="white", command = darkmd)
bt_darkmd.grid(row=7, column=0)

lb_tasks = Listbox(root,fg="black", bg="white")
lb_tasks.grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=9)

#--------main
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your problem starts here: `from tkinter.ttk import *`. Dont't use `*`!

Comment: I suggest you not to use this package. It has not good documentation and it is not stable.

Comment: @JacobFuchs What would you suggest?

Comment: @stovfl thank you, but somehow the theme stay the same as before

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `ThemedTk`, you can use `ThemedStyle`. This way your code will be exactly like if you were using one of the standard ttk themes except that you define your style with `style = ThemedStyle(root)` instead of `style = Style(root)`. Then you simply use `style.theme_use(<theme name>)` to change theme and you can list the available themes with  `style.theme_names()`.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle


#--------root style
root = tk.Tk()
#--------root backgroud
root.configure(bg="white")
#--------root title
root.title("Reminder")
#--------root size
root.geometry("225x300")

# white theme
style = ThemedStyle(root)
style.theme_use('arc')  # white style

#--------create empty list
tasks = []


#--------function
def darkmd():
    style.theme_use("equilux")  # only changes the theme of the ttk widgets
    # change style of tk widgets manually:
    bg = style.lookup('TLabel', 'background')
    fg = style.lookup('TLabel', 'foreground')
    root.configure(bg=style.lookup('TLabel', 'background'))
    lb_tasks.configure(bg=bg, fg=fg)


#--------command
lbl_title = ttk.Label(root, text="ToDoList")
lbl_title.grid(row=0, column=0)

lbl_display = ttk.Label(root, text="")
lbl_display.grid(row=0, column=1)

txt_input = ttk.Entry(root, width=20)
txt_input.grid(row=1, column=1)

bt_add_task = ttk.Button(root, text="Add Task")
bt_add_task.grid(row=1, column=0)

bt_del_all = ttk.Button(root, text="Del all")
bt_del_all.grid(row=2, column=0)

bt_del_one = ttk.Button(root, text="Del")
bt_del_one.grid(row=3, column=0)

bt_sort_asc = ttk.Button(root, text="Sort (ASC)")
bt_sort_asc.grid(row=4, column=0)

bt_sort_desc = ttk.Button(root, text="Sort (DESC)")
bt_sort_desc.grid(row=5, column=0)

bt_total_task = ttk.Button(root, text="Num Of Task")
bt_total_task.grid(row=6, column=0)

bt_darkmd = ttk.Button(root, text="Darkmode", command=darkmd)
bt_darkmd.grid(row=7, column=0)

lb_tasks = tk.Listbox(root, fg="black")
lb_tasks.grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=9)

#--------main
root.mainloop()
```

Clear theme: [image: screenshot clear theme]
Dark theme: [image: screenshot dark theme]

Note that only the ttk widgets become dark after setting the theme to "equilux". So you need to manually change the colors of your tk widgets in `darkmd()` (like I did for `root` and `lb_tasks`).

Answer (score 2):

> **Comment**: HowTo using: [ttkthemes](https://github.com/RedFantom/ttkthemes)

To use `ttkthemes` change to the following:
**No** `style.theme_use(...` statement, as this is alredy done in `__init__(...`.

```
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

class App(ThemedTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("equilux")

        # ATTENTION!!
        # The following could fail as i couldn't test with `ThemedTk`
        # ATTENTION!!
        style = ttk.Style(self)
        style.configure("TLabel", background="white")
```

---

> **Question**: How to add themes?

First you have to understand, **not** to **mix** `tkinter` and `tkinter.ttk` widgets in a uncontrolled way. **Only** `tkinter.ttk` widgets can be styled using `theme` and `style`.

- [TkDocs - Tk Tutorial - Styles and Themes](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html)
- [tkinterbook - Widget Styling](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm)

---

1. Use only the following common `import` statements

   ```
   import tkinter as tk
   import tkinter.ttk as ttk
   ```
2. To instantiate a `ttk` widget use:

   > **Note**: You can't use `bg=` on a `ttk` widget!

   ```
   lbl_title = ttk.Label(root, text="ToDoList")
   ```
3. Application wide usage:

   > **Note**: It's **important** to do all style definition **once** and **before** any widget instantiation.

   ```
   class App(tk.Tk):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()

           style = ttk.Style(self)
           style.theme_use('clam')
           style.configure("TLabel", background="white")

           self.title("Tkinter Style")
           self.geometry("225x300")

           lbl_title = ttk.Label(self, text="ToDoList")
           lbl_title.grid(row=0, column=0)


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       App().mainloop()
   ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Comment: i did everything you said but same result.Is there a simpler way to add like a dark_mode button like when you press it the theme will go full matte black?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: *"what you mean"*:Try the part with `ttkthemes` and comment if it works or not.

Answer (score -2):

After reading your comment, I thought my input may help.

First, identify your OS. Windows/Mac

Second, open IDLE and then open IDLE preferences

You will see the settings and in "Highlights", below the radio buttons for the themes, you will see a drop box that allows you to switch your themes from IDLE Dark to Classic and New!

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the poster is asking; try aiming your answer more specifically to the question.